# Why isn't it possible to access the root account directly in Fedora?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, fedora, root

Why isn't it possible to access the root account directly in Fedora?

In CentOS and Ubuntu we can access it, but why not in Fedora? What is the security reason for this?

Comment: Regardless of which OS has this restriction, the reason (as given in slhck's link) is *"doing daily work as the SuperUser can be dangerous. You could type a command incorrectly and destroy the system. Ideally, you run as a user that has only the privileges needed for the task at hand."* We can surmise that this decision may  be the result of an analysis of the proportion of support calls that result from inexperienced people using the root account when they don't need to.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the root account directly in Ubuntu? That's news to me. Ubuntu [explicitly restricts access](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo) to the root account for security purposes:

> By default, the Root account password is locked in Ubuntu. This means that you cannot login as Root directly or use the su command to become the Root user.

In Fedora however, you set a dedicated root password during installation. [To become root](http://www.fedorafaq.org/basics/#root), the following command should be enough:

```
su -
```

Comment: I think from Ubuntu it is possible see this this [link](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2011/03/login-root-ubuntu-11-04-natty-narwhal/)

Comment: Yeah, of course it's *possible*, but not enabled by default. What is your question then? Are you strictly talking about *graphical* logins?

Comment: yes, but i got the anwer, thanks for your valuable reply...

Comment: Since you're new here: If you want to accept an answer, please do so by clicking the green checkmark next to it. This also applies to your other questions. Or you want RedGrittyBrick to post an answer himself?